# "print()" não apresenta os elementos da lista inseridas

Tags: python, lista

Por que a instrução abaixo não funciona? Ele apresenta a última nota, e não a lista com todas as notas.

```
jnotas = int(input("quantas notas você já tem = "))
 
for c in range (0, jnotas):
    notas1 = []
    n = float(input("entre com sua nota = "))
    notas1.append(n)
    
print(notas1)
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Você está iniciando a lista dentro do laço, então toda vez que passa por ali a lista é zerada, só guarda o último elemento digitado.

```
quantidade = int(input("quantas notas você já tem = "))
notas = []
for c in range (0, quantidade):
    notas.append(float(input("entre com sua nota = ")))
print(notas)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZUzYhp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yadpqvyg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/Loop.py).

Comment: muito obrigado ! tenho que prestar atenção a essas coisas !

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi respondido `anteriormente` você está inicializando a lista dentro do laço `for`. Desta forma, a cada iteração do `for` os elementos da lista são sobrescritos. O correto é você implementa a lista `fora` do for, tal como no código abaixo...

```
jnotas = int(input("quantas notas você já tem = "))

notas1 = []
for c in range(0, jnotas):
    n = float(input("entre com sua nota = "))
    notas1.append(n)

print(notas1)
```

Agora, se você deseja dar `mais legibilidade` ao seu código, você pode implementar o seguinte código abaixo...

```
quant_notas = int(input('Desejas inserir quantas notas? '))

notas = list()
for c in range(1, quant_notas + 1):
    n = float(input(f'Entre com sua {c}ª nota: '))
    notas.append(n)

print(f'\033[32mAs notas digitadas são: {notas}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/dmztlqdn-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Outra coisa, se você deseja `exibir cada valor por linha` e sem exibir os `colchetes`, você pode utilizar este código...

```
quant_notas = int(input('Desejas inserir quantas notas? '))

notas = list()
for c in range(1, quant_notas + 1):
    n = float(input(f'Entre com sua {c}ª nota: '))
    notas.append(n)

for nota in notas:
    print(f'\033[32m{nota}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/cwhbpurc-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Se ao invés disso, você desejar `exibir` os elementos da lista em `uma só linha`, separados por `vírgula` e sem delimitadores `colchetes`, você pode utilizar o seguinte código...

```
quant_notas = int(input('Desejas inserir quantas notas? '))

notas = list()
for c in range(1, quant_notas + 1):
    n = float(input(f'Entre com sua {c}ª nota: '))
    notas.append(n)

print(f'\033[32mAs notas são:')
for nota in notas:
    print(f'{nota}', end='')
    print(', ' if nota < notas[-1] else '. ', end='')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/jddpntgy-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Se for o caso, de você querer `reduzir` a quantidade de linhas de códigos, você pode utilizar o próximo algoritmo. Neste algoritmo, você terá que digitar `todos` os valores na mesma linha e `separados` por `um` espaço.

```
quant_notas = list(map(float, input('Insira aqui todas as notas separadas por um espaço: ').split()))
print(f'\033[32mAs notas são: {quant_notas}\033[m')
```

Se você deseja exibir os elementos da lista em `uma só linha`, sem `vírgulas ou pontos` e sem delimitadores `colchetes`, podes utilizar este algoritmo...

```
quant_notas = list(map(float, input('Insira aqui todas notas separadas por um espaço: ').split()))
print('A notas são: ', *quant_notas)
```

Agora, se desejas exibir `cada` valor por linha, com um determinado `espaçamento` temporal, podes implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from time import sleep

quant_notas = int(input('Desejas inserir quantas notas? '))

notas = list()
for c in range(1, quant_notas + 1):
    n = float(input(f'Entre com sua {c}ª nota: '))
    notas.append(n)

cont = 0
for nota in notas:
    cont += 1
    sleep(0.4)
    print(f'\033[32mA {cont}ª nota é: {nota}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/dpfmafms-solkarped) o funcionamento deste algoritmo.